# Undo setkey() on data.table in R

Tags: r, duplicates, key, data.table

I have a `data.table` (`data` in the following) with 10 columns (`C1, ..., C10`) and I want to delete duplicate rows.

I accidentally used `setkey(data,C1)`, so now when I run `unique(data)` I only get unique rows based on the column `C1`, while I want to remove a row only if it's identical to another one on all the columns `C1, ..., C10`.
Is there a way to undo the `setkey()` operation? I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552181/how-do-you-undo-a-setkey-ordering-in-data-table) but it didn't help to solve my provlem.

PS: I can get around the problem by setting all columns in my `data.table` as keys with `setkeyv(data, paste0("C", 1:10))`, but this is not at all an elegant/practical solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, you can use `setkey(data, NULL)` to remove the key.

Second, `unique.data.table` has a `by` option which will allow you to specify on the fly which columns to use for comparison (regardless of which key is currently set):

```
unique(data, by = paste0("C", 1:10))
```

Third, instead of using `setkey` for many keys, use `setkeyv` to pass a `character` vector:

```
setkeyv(data, paste0("C", 1:10))
```

A thorough reading of `?setkey` and `?unique.data.table` can provide some more details.